# HashMap. Create entry (int, string[]) and push into value immediately

Tags: c#, algorithm, file, dictionary

I want to get all files of the same size in buckets according, size is a key.

Default behaviour would override the value whenever you associate it with an existing key. I want to push a value to string[] array whenever the same value is met.
1556 - "1.txt" - Entry added to the dictionary, 1.txt put to the string[]
1556 - "7.txt" - 7.txt pushed to the string[] associated with 1556

My current thought is to enumerate once through all files and create entries with keys and empty arrays in the dictionary:

```
foreach(var file in directory){
map[file.length] = new string[]/List<string>();
```

then enumerate second time retrieving array associated with current key:

```
foreach(var file in directory){
map[file.length].push(file.name);
}
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want entries to consist of fileSize as keys,
fileNames array as value.

In that case, I'd suggest to use just one loop, like so:

```
foreach(var file in directory)
{
    if (!map.ContainsKey(file.Length)) 
    {
        map.Add(file.Length, new List<string>());
    }
    map[file.Length].Add(file.Name);
}
```

Edit: removed space for each file name.

Comment: Curious why you'd append a space to the filename when you're inserting it into a `List<string>`. Doesn't seem like you'd need it. And space is a particularly poor choice, considering that file names can contain spaces.

Comment: Indeed! No space needed here. Somehow I thought that it is one string, not `List<string>`. I will edit it.